# Persistent ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.10

Thank you for looking,

I have been having a hard time.

I am using oracle virtualbox virtual machine and upuntu 22.04 lts operating system. I want to run a python3 code. When I write the code:

```
 python3 (file-name-to-run).py
```

the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LoRaSim'
```

I use pip3 install LoRaSim command, it tells me that the requirement already satisfied and gives me the location of the library which is:

```
/home/kawther/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.0.1)
```

Knowing that the python3.10 folder does not have the site-packages folder.

Please consider that i have number of versions of the python, those are (2.7, 3, 3.10 and 3.11). Moreover, I checked for the system path,

```
python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

I found that the python3 uses all of the paths where the libraries exist.

Any help here is appreciated.